# Prepopulating a UITextField with Core Data and NSFetchedResultsControllers

Tags: ios, core-data, uitextfield, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a simple application and I require a bit of assistance with one new feature.

The application is a table view (TV1) which is populated by the user adding an entry (a button in the navigation bar which modally brings up a new view controller for the user filling in a name, event and amount text field and selecting a date from the date picker).

The table view controller is part of a tab bar controller where the first tab shows everything (timeline) and the second tab shows just the list of events. If you click on an event, you segue over to see all transactions with that event.

I've added a bar button item here as well which segues to the Add Entry view controller, with the aim of having the event already selected.

What I mean by this is:

Say you have 3 events called Wedding, Birthday and Anniversary in your transactions. If you click on the Event tab, you'll see Wedding, Birthday and Anniversary in a Table view. Clicking Birthday will show you all the transactions where event = Birthday.

I have a bar button item which will allow me to add entries from this screen, but because it's coming from the Birthday event, I want that event text field to already be filled in, in the Add Entry with the name of this event (Birthday in this case).

I'm using Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController.

The situation right now is, when I press the button to add a new entry from the Selected Event (Birthday), it's not pre-configuring the event text field with Birthday in the Add Entry screen.

Here's some code which should hopefully explain what I'm doing.

From the Event Tab

```
// This segues over to the selected event (Birthday). 
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.eventTableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    Occasion *selectedOccasion = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Selected Occasion Segue"])
    {
        ESelectedOccasionTableViewController *selectedOccasionTVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        [selectedOccasionTVC setOccasion:selectedOccasion];
    }
}
```

From the Selected Event Tab (Birthday), I create two segues, one for editing a cell and one for creating a new entry:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.selectedOccasionTableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    Transaction *seletedTransaction = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // The first segue is to "edit" the existing entry
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Editable Cell"])
    {
        EDetailViewController *dvc = (EDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        dvc.selectedTransaction = seletedTransaction;
    }
    // This segue is to create a new entry from the event
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Create New Entry From Event"])
    {
        EddEntryViewController *eAppEntryViewController = (EAddEntryViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        [eAppEntryViewController setSelectedTransaction:selectedTransaction]; 
    }
}
```

The first segue is for editing the cell (which works perfectly), but in the second segue, the one I'm interested in here, I'm not actually clicking on a cell; I'm clicking on a bar button item which will modally bring up the add entry. I want to take just the "event" (Birthday) from this Table View and pre-fill the "event text field" in the Add Entry.

```
The setSelectedTransaction in the Add Entry is:

- (void)setSelectedTransaction:(Transaction *)selectedTransaction
{
    _selectedTransaction = selectedTransaction;
    self.occasionTextField.text = _selectedTransaction.occasion.title;
}
```

I can't imagine I'm very far from getting this working, but any assistance on this would really be great because I'm really stuck.

Should I be setting something in viewDidLoad? (That did not work either).

I'm not selecting a table view cell which is why I understand that the         [eAppEntryViewController setSelectedTransaction:selectedTransaction];  line isn't actually passing anything, because I'm clicking on a bar button item, not a table view cell.

The model is: a Transaction Entity that links to the Date and Event Entities.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue in the following way:

```
 EAddEntryViewController *eAppEntryViewController = (EAddEntryViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    [eAppEntryViewController setSelectedEvent:self.occasion.title];
```

Which called:

```
- (void)setSelectedEvent:(NSString *)selectedEvent
{
    _selectedEvent = selectedEvent;
}
```

In the viewWillAppear, I did:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.occasionTextField.text = self.selectedEvent;
}
```

This works the way it is and I'm happy with this.

Comment: This feels clunky, but something similar worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

So I might not be understanding the question fully. But you can add a "Touch Up Inside" event to the bar button item and then pull the text from the "sender" object. Then, either store that text as an NSString property in the interface for later use, or set your desired textbox straight from the bar button item action.

Comment: Thanks Ross - how would something like that work? Like how would I go about achieving something like that? Also.. I don't see how I'd get the date across as well - isn't there anyway I can use my existing technology to get this to work?